# Question about consumer and producer threads

Tags: c, thread-sleep

I'm having an issue with my sleep cycles in the ProducerConsumer.h file. If I comment out the sleep(rnum) the program will access the line printf("producer produced %d\n", item); If it's not commented out it will never access that line and I cant figure out why.
Here is my code it's in 3 separate files I would be grateful of any help thank you.

buffer.h:

```
typedef int buffer_item;
#define BUFFER_SIZE 5


int insert_item(buffer_item item);
int remove_item(buffer_item *item);
```

ProducerConsumer.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* required for rand() */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "buffer.h"
#define RAND_DIVISOR 100000000;
#define TRUE 1

int counter;
buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
sem_t full, empty;

/* Producer Thread */
void *producer(void *param) {
    buffer_item item;

    while(TRUE) {
      /* sleep for a random period of time */
      int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
      sleep(rNum);
      printf("producer produced %d\n", item);

      /* generate a random number */
      item = rand();

      /* acquire the empty lock */
      sem_wait(&empty);

      /* acquire the mutex lock */
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

      if(insert_item(item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, " Producer report error condition\n");
      } else {
         printf("producer produced %d\n", item);
      }

      /* release the mutex lock */
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

      /* signal full */
      sem_post(&full);
    }

}

/* Consumer Thread */
void *consumer(void *param) {
    buffer_item item;

    while(TRUE) {
      /* sleep for a random period of time */

      int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
       sleep(rNum);
      /* aquire the full lock */

      sem_wait(&full);
      /* aquire the mutex lock */

      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      if(remove_item(&item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Consumer report error condition\n");
      } else {
         printf("consumer consumed %d\n", item);`enter code here`
      }

      /* release the mutex lock */
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

      /* signal empty */
      sem_post(&empty);
    }
}

int insert_item(buffer_item item) {
    if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
      buffer[counter] = item;
      counter++;
      return 0;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
}

int remove_item(buffer_item *item) {
    if(counter > 0) {
      *item = buffer[(counter-1)];
      counter--;
      return 0;
     } else {
      return -1;
     }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "ProducerConsumer.h"
#include "buffer.h"

pthread_t tid;
pthread_attr_t attr;

void initializeData()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    counter = 0;
}

int main() {
   int i;
   int numProd = 5; /* Number of producer threads */
   int numCons = 5; /* Number of consumer threads */

   initializeData();

   /* Create the producer threads */
   for(i = 0; i < numProd; i++) {
      /* Create the thread */
      pthread_create(&tid,&attr,producer,NULL);
    }

   /* Create the consumer threads */
   for(i = 0; i < numCons; i++) {
      /* Create the thread */
      pthread_create(&tid,&attr,consumer,NULL);
   }

   void *producer(void *param);
   void *consumer(void *param);

   /* Exit the program */
   printf("Exit the program\n");

   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Those who rush for the exit may never see the sights.

Comment: Try `join`-ing your pthreads before `exit`-ing your main process...

Comment: Other than the `.cpp` file extension, everything looks to be `C`.  Just curious why use `.cpp` file extensions?

Comment: the return of `rand()` is at least `32767`.  if you want the statement `int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;` to be longer than 0 seconds, change the value of your denominator to a smaller number.  or just use `rand() % 10`, for example to give a range of numbers between 0 and 9.

Comment: Hey everyone thanks for the comments. The .cpp file extension is because I'm coming from c++ to c. I didn't think when I made the file and the other 2 files are from my textbook.

Comment: cleblanc what do you mean by joining them before exiting my main process. Before I move into the ProducerConsumer processes or before I end the program?

Answer (score 0):

The RAND_MAX value is likely at least `32767`, causing the the following line:

```
int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;// defined as 100000000
```

to most always set `rNum` == 0.

Change statement to get a non-zero value:

```
int rNum = 1 + rand() % 10;// yields 1-10
```

Also, call *[srand()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_srand.htm)* one time, and before using `rand()`.  eg:

```
void *producer(void *param) {
    buffer_item item;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you I'm trying what you suggested right now. I've changed my rNum formula now I'm working on getting the srand() function to work.

Comment: Hi, so I made those changes and I am getting a number between 1 and 10 now however, my program still won't enter the if else statements for printing the objects that were created. I'll keep working on it and any hints or help you could give would be appreciated thanks again.

Comment: @AJFarmer - If you do not already have a favorite debugger, _[such as this one for example](https://www.cprogramming.com/gdb.html)_, its time to pick one and learn to use it.  With it, you can set a break point, and step through your code to see where execution flow is not doing what you expect.  Suggest also reading the documentation (and examples) for _[sem_wait(&empty);](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html)_

Comment: Hey ryyker, i use GDB mostly but I'm not very familiar with it. I'll try the break point thing and see if that leads me anywhere thank you.